# WCF receiving a request with a SWA payload

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

We have a requirement to build a WCF web service that uploads a document into Sharepoint. Our Enterprise service Bus is a IBM product called WPS (websphere process server) and the request is coming from is another IBM product call BTT ( Bank Transformation Toolkit). both of these products, in there installed version, do not support MTOM but they do support SwA. We are now investigating building a custom binding to support SwA. Has anyone tried this and able to share there experience?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use SOAP with Attachments instead of MTOM you need custom message encoder = custom channel used in custom binding. You can build your own following [SwA specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/SOAP-attachments) or you can try [this one from CodePlex](http://wcfswaencoder.codeplex.com/).