# C# Consuming SOAP webservice returns document

Tags: c#, soap

I am trying to consume SOAP Webservice which is suppose to return Document.
Following is WSDL for output.

```
<wsdl:binding name="NGOImageEnableServiceImpHttpBinding" type="ns:NGOImageEnableServiceImpPortType">
      <http:binding verb="POST"/>
       <wsdl:operation name="downloadDocInFile">
         <http:operation location="NGOImageEnableServiceImp/downloadDocInFile"/>
           <wsdl:input>
             <mime:content type="text/xml" part="downloadDocInFile"/>
           </wsdl:input>
           <wsdl:output>
             <mime:content type="text/xml" part="downloadDocInFile"/>
           </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    </wsdl:binding>
```

And Binding i have set in web.config is

```
<webHttpBinding>

        <binding name="NGOImageEnableServiceImpSoap12Binding" 
            allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false"
            hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
            maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
            transferMode="Streamed">
        </binding>
```

Same service gives output like this while using postman

```
--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_C455EAC131FBC506CE1521635293615
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: 
<0.urn:uuid:C455EAC131FBC506CE1521635293616@apache.org>
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <soapenv:Body>
            <ns:downloadDocInFileResponse xmlns:ns="http://provider.ws.jts.omni.newgen.com">
                <ns:return>
                    <swa:fileName xmlns:swa="http://provider.ws.jts.omni.newgen.com">
                        <swa:graph>urn:uuid:C455EAC131FBC506CE1521635293614</swa:graph>
                        <swa:message>file download on server successfully</swa:message>
                    </swa:fileName>
                </ns:return>
            </ns:downloadDocInFileResponse>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_C455EAC131FBC506CE1521635293615
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-ID:
    <urn:uuid:C455EAC131FBC506CE1521635293614>
    ****BINARY CONTENT****
```

I want to consume this in my c# code.

Comment: You can use Ajax method in frontEnd or HttpRequest in backEnd for getting your result.

Comment: Yes off course i did that and i am only getting this response
{
      "swa:fileName": {
        "@xmlns:swa": "http://provider.ws.jts.omni.newgen.com",
        "swa:graph": "urn:uuid:C455EAC131FBC506CE1521701266617",
        "swa:message": "file download on server successfully"
      }
    }

Comment: There must be a Msdn article on this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After working on this i found the solution with the help of MultipartMemoryStreamProvider

```
async static Task<string> readMultipart(HttpWebResponse httpResponse)
        {
            var content = new StreamContent(httpResponse.GetResponseStream());
            content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", httpResponse.ContentType);


            MultipartMemoryStreamProvider multipart = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            Task.Factory.StartNew(() => multipart = content.ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result,
               CancellationToken.None,
               TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning, // guarantees separate thread
               TaskScheduler.Default)
               .Wait();
            String filename = "";
            String json = await multipart.Contents[0].ReadAsStringAsync();


            string path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/test.jpeg");
            byte[] fileData = multipart.Contents[1].ReadAsByteArrayAsync().Result;
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(path, fileData);
            return json;
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ugh! This is a SOAP-With-Attachments (SWA). WCF does not support this. WCF uses MTOM but I think there are workarounds:

- [How to receive a soap message with attachment in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577192/how-to-receive-a-soap-message-with-attachment-in-wcf)
- [WCF receiving a request with a SWA payload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6740776/wcf-receiving-a-request-with-a-swa-payload)
- https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=wcfswaencoder
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ece5fe46-0b05-4fed-a6a1-d24ecab93bcb/wcf-and-soap-with-attachments?forum=wcf
- https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Send-Soap-with-Attachments-3784e5f6
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/9152642e-fb81-4755-af92-ec2a2fa954f6/receive-swa-messages-with-wcf?forum=wcf

Comment: How can i save that attachment using c# ? any way to do that ?